# How to use input file type in javascript client side and server side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I use input file=”type” and I want to priview the image and then to use this image details in server side..

This is priview the image but I can’t use it in server side, to put in db:

```
<input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelected();"/>
```

And if I do:

```
<input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelected();" runat="server"/>
```

So I don’t get a preview image.

I try to copy image_file value to new input type=”text” image_file2 like this:

```
<input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelected();"/>
<input type="file" name="image_file2" id="image_file2" runat="server" onchange="document.getElementById('image_file') = this;"/>
```

But it’s not working...

What can I do?

Comment: I've formatted your code for you. Make sure you use the code format functionality when asking question so people can read your code (check the preview before posting the question!) Also, you need to describe "not working" as that can mean just about anything.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your code?

Comment: What is the code for `fileSelected` ?

Comment: How do you setup the preview? I suspect `runat="server"` breaks everything simply because the ID is changing

Comment: I create a web site, 
And one of the pages has an option to upload picture to website. 
I want the user to be able to see a preview (and more picture details) of the image before he click upload, so there is a function  fileSelected() does this. 
But when I add runat = "server" to image_file - it does preview.

Comment: One option would be to upload it, let them see it, and if they don't click save, delete it from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly

http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/

or

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459419/995762